# Cassandra(with Hadoop) performance with Spark

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, cassandra

We are running Spark/Hadoop on a different set of nodes than Cassandra. We have 10 Cassandra nodes and multiple spark cores but Cassandra is not running on Hadoop. Performance in fetching data from Cassandra through spark(in yarn client mode) is not very good and bulk data reads from HDFS are faster(6 mins in Cassandra to 2 mins in HDFS). Changing Spark-Cassandra parameters is not helping much also.

Will deploying Hadoop on top of Cassandra solve this issue and majorly impact read performance ?

Comment: I've never heard of "Hadoop on Cassandra". Did you mean "storing Cassandra data on HDFS"?. Datastax has there own alternative to CFS https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/dse-dev/datastax_enterprise/analytics/cfsAbout.html

Comment: I meant running Cassandra and spark/hadoop on the same nodes/cluster

Answer (score 0):

Without looking at your code, bulk reads in an analytics/Spark capacity, are always going to be faster when directly going to the file VS. reading from a database. The database offers other advantages such as schema enforcement, availability, distribution control, etc but I think the performance differences you're seeing are normal.